# Count unique ips in log file, with regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to match only unique ips on a log file using negative lookahead in regex. The reason for this is because i am trying to do the counting using only notepad ++ :)
I cant seem to get it right for some reason though, there are repeating matches.
Rerex : `(\d*?\.\d*?\.\d*?\.\d*)(?!\1)`
Part of log:

```
24.90.247.245 - - [16/May/2014:04:43:37 -0400] "GET /rd/index.shtml HTTP/1.1" 200 263 "-" "-"
132.199.208.13 - - [16/May/2014:04:43:38 -0400] "GET /rd/index.shtml HTTP/1.1" 200 300 "-" "-"
58.152.254.32 - - [16/May/2014:04:43:38 -0400] "GET /rd/index.shtml HTTP/1.1" 200 300 "-" "-"
58.152.254.32 - - [16/May/2014:04:43:38 -0400] "GET /rd/index.shtml HTTP/1.1" 200 300 "-" "-"
134.176.77.200 - - [16/May/2014:04:43:39 -0400] "GET /rd/index.shtml HTTP/1.1" 200 300 "-" "-"
151.97.52.74 - - [16/May/2014:04:43:40 -0400] "GET /rd/index.shtml HTTP/1.1" 200 263 "-" "-"
50.31.10.96 - - [16/May/2014:04:43:40 -0400] "GET /rd/index.shtml HTTP/1.1" 200 244 "-" "-"
223.87.53.36 - - [16/May/2014:04:43:41 -0400] "GET /rd/index.shtml HTTP/1.1" 200 300 "-" "-"
213.202.50.177 - - [16/May/2014:04:43:43 -0400] "GET /rd/index.shtml HTTP/1.1" 200 263 "-" "-"
216.40.65.205 - - [16/May/2014:04:43:43 -0400] "GET /rd/index.shtml HTTP/1.1" 200 263 "-" "-"
147.83.107.157 - - [16/May/2014:04:43:43 -0400] "GET /rd/index.shtml HTTP/1.1" 200 263 "-" "-"
24.92.240.190 - - [16/May/2014:04:43:44 -0400] "GET /rd/index.shtml HTTP/1.1" 200 263 "-" "-"
137.248.75.218 - - [16/May/2014:04:43:45 -0400] "GET /rd/index.shtml HTTP/1.1" 200 263 "-" "-"
147.213.74.167 - - [16/May/2014:04:43:45 -0400] "GET /rd/index.shtml HTTP/1.1" 200 300 "-" "-"
54.226.75.239 - - [16/May/2014:04:43:46 -0400] "GET /rd/index.shtml HTTP/1.1" 200 300 "-" "-"
218.42.9.181 - - [16/May/2014:04:43:46 -0400] "GET /rd/index.shtml HTTP/1.1" 200 300 "-" "-"
150.140.182.17 - - [16/May/2014:04:43:47 -0400] "GET /rd/index.shtml HTTP/1.1" 200 300 "-" "-"
24.213.205.187 - - [16/May/2014:04:43:47 -0400] "GET /rd/index.shtml HTTP/1.1" 200 263 "-" "-"
209.181.139.29 - - [16/May/2014:04:43:47 -0400] "GET /rd/index.shtml HTTP/1.1" 200 263 "-" "-"
183.223.170.34 - - [16/May/2014:04:43:48 -0400] "GET /rd/index.shtml HTTP/1.1" 200 300 "-" "-"
216.59.242.112 - - [16/May/2014:04:43:48 -0400] "GET /rd/index.shtml HTTP/1.1" 200 263 "-" "-"
142.134.234.249 - - [16/May/2014:04:43:48 -0400] "GET /rd/index.shtml HTTP/1.1" 200 263 "-" "-"
130.237.254.155 - - [16/May/2014:04:43:48 -0400] "GET /rd/index.shtml HTTP/1.1" 200 263 "-" "-"
5.254.134.181 - - [16/May/2014:04:43:49 -0400] "GET /rd/index.shtml HTTP/1.1" 200 300 "-" "-"
24.90.247.245 - - [16/May/2014:04:43:49 -0400] "GET /rd/index.shtml HTTP/1.1" 200 263 "-" "-"
128.205.64.53 - - [16/May/2014:04:43:49 -0400] "GET /rd/index.shtml HTTP/1.1" 200 263 "-" "-"
```

Comment: `cat log_file | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort | uniq -c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the regex that the IP could be anywhere ahead; also meaning there can be a lot of characters between the IP and the next one. Thus, you might want to try this:

```
(\d*?\.\d*?\.\d*?\.\d*)(?!.*?\1)
```

And check the `. matches newline` checkbox as well to make `.` make line breaks.

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesnt work because it fails for memory reasons >:(

Comment: @Evan Well, you could take it to excel and there, I'm sure it'd be faster :) it's easy to see if there are duplicates in excel.